# Show only one message after foreach with promise.then AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, promise, angular-promise

Hello guys I have this function call in AngularJS using REST in a confirmation button. The saving is okay, the issue happens in success or error messages. It should show only one success message after execution of the loop if succeded, or show the error messsage on any error more than once. I used a flag isError to get if an error happened, but it doesn`t matter what I do, the "if (isError == false){" always is executed before the end of the loop.

```
 $scope.confirm = function () {
        var isError = false;
        var i=0;
        $scope.displayedmodalcollection.forEach(function(item) {
            i++;
            delete item.added;
            result = DataBase.update({
                id: item._id,
                endpoint: item._type
            }, item._source).$promise.then(function(response) {

            }, function(err) {
                isError = true;
                if (err.status === 500) {
                    ngToast.create({
                        className: 'warning',
                        content: String.format('Any message.', item._id)
                    });
                }
                else if (err.status === 404) {
                    ngToast.create({
                        className: 'danger',
                        content: '404 - other message'
                    });
                } else {
                    ngToast.create({
                        className: 'danger',
                        content: 'Error'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        if (isError == false){

            ngToast.create({
                className: 'success',
                content: 'Success'
            });
        }
     };
```

Does anyone has a suggestion for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$q.all()` to show the success toast based upon all the updates resolving

Instead of :

```
$scope.displayedmodalcollection.forEach(function(item) {
```

Do something like

```
// map array of update promises
var updatePromises = $scope.displayedmodalcollection.map(function(item){
   // return the promise
   return DataBase.update({...}).$promise.then(function(response) {
               // success code
            }, function(err) {
               // error code
            });    
});    

$q.all(updatePromises).then(function(){
      // all promises were resolved
      ngToast.create({
                className: 'success',
                content: 'Success'
      });
});
```

Remember to inject $q in controller

Comment: That doesn't make sure that the success toast occurs at the end of the loop though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to handle successful updates and errors, but this should put you on the right track:

```
$scope.confirm = function() {
    var successes = 0;
    var errors = 0;
    $scope.displayedmodalcollection.forEach(function(item) {
        delete item.added;
        result = DataBase.update({
            id: item._id,
            endpoint: item._type
        }, item._source).$promise.then(function(response) {
            successes++;
            checkStatus(successes, errors);
        }, function(err) {
            errors++;
            checkStatus(successes, errors);
            if (err.status === 500) {
                ngToast.create({
                    className: 'warning',
                    content: String.format('Any message.', item._id)
                });
            } else if (err.status === 404) {
                ngToast.create({
                    className: 'danger',
                    content: '404 - other message'
                });
            } else {
                ngToast.create({
                    className: 'danger',
                    content: 'Error'
                });
            }
        });
    });
};

function checkStatus(successes, errors) {
    var isCompleted = (successes + errors) == $scope.displayedmodalcollection.length;
    var notAllFailed = successes > 0;
    if (isCompleted && notAllFailed) {
        handleSuccessToast();
    }
}

function handleSuccessToast() {
    ngToast.create({
        className: 'success',
        content: 'Success'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the success logic in the `isError == false` branch is being executed before all of the DB calls have completed.  As a result, it is being run potentially before the errors have actually occurred, therefore the flag is false and the branch is followed.

This happens because the DB logic is returning promises.  Promises do not block execution of the rest of your code - they just defer the logic that is contained in the 'then' callback until the DB call actually completes.  So if you had 5 items in your collection, you could initiate the DB calls for all 5 items before any of them actually completed.  The key is that you need to make your success logic wait until you know that all of the DB promises have been resolved and all calls are complete.  See [this Promise guide](http://www.dwmkerr.com/promises-in-angularjs-the-definitive-guide/) for more about promises.

Here is an example of how you might code your logic to wait for all promises to resolve before you check if any errors occurred:

```
var doneCount = 0;
var isError = false;
something.foreach(item) {
    somedblogic(item).$promise.then(function (response) {
        if (++doneCount === something.length && !isError) {
            //-- success logic here - runs one time after all db calls complete
        }
    },function (err) {
        doneCount++;
        isError = true;
        //-- rest of error logic here - runs once for each error returned
    });
}
```